# MATLAB Error : Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, octave

Hi I get the this error with the following script -

The script :

```
fid = fopen('TR2.roi', 'r');

test = []; % test variable for holding current line from text file
while isempty(test)

    fline = fgetl(fid);
    disp('b');
    test = strmatch('; Number of',fline); 
end
```

The error:

```
Error using fgets
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in fgetl (line 36)
[tline,lt] = fgets(fid);

Error in test1 (line 6)
    fline = fgetl(fid);
```

Any solutions and reason why this error? I have verified my fid it is >2.

Comment: Use `[fid,err] = fopen('TR2.roi', 'r');`, any error message?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I get the same error and the `err` is an empty string.

Comment: Did fid = 0 ? If yes, file isn't open. Fid must be a number >= 1.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, fid is >2 in every attempt I made. Currently it is 31 and that is what is bugging me.

Comment: The **fid** being 31 may make sense if the file is never closed properly with **fclose(fid)**.  From the command line, just type *fclose all** to close all open files (except 0,1,and 2 - see _help close_ for details).  On the subsequent fopen, the fid should be 3.

Comment: @anon can you open the file using a different application (e.g., notepad)?